# Bootstrap submenu not working when linked externally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4.3.1 navbar with a submenu and it works fine when I include it in the navbar. However, according to [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#external-content), I should be able to link it externally. When I do that, the general toggle button works, but the submenu no longer works. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's my navbar:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Brand Logo</a>
  <!--NAV BAR -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-dark" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="far fa-circle"></i> Dropdown Title
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- tag added by community -->
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I'm trying to move the entire #navbarCollapse div into a different page and still have the submenu function properly.

Comment: You miss a `</div>` before `</nav>`. Is that solving the problem?

Comment: sorry, that's in my code. idk why it got left off here but thats not the problem unfortunately...

Comment: Seems to work. Please revise the snippet I created to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. An "external" element isn't one on another page. It's one outside the navbar container on the same page. I'm not sure what that would even look like.